# Create a mosaic from every available cloud free image over the study area and batch export from GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, mosaic

I have a study area that encompasses several images. I would like to create a mosaic for the entire study area and export it as a single image for every possible date for which imagery is available.

Here is what I am using to create the mosaic. Most of this code has been taken from elsewhere and seems to fit the bill.

With the mosaics though, I want to calculate NDVI, a threshold it and export just the thresholded NDVI band.

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

//add study area
var studyarea = ee.FeatureCollection('users/XXX/XXXXXX/studyarea');

Map.addLayer(studyarea, {color: 'red'}, 'Study Area');
Map.centerObject(studyarea);

// Filter the collection for the VV product from the descending track
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var Date_Start = ee.Date('2020-06-01');
var Date_End = ee.Date('2020-10-30');
var num_months_in_interval = 1;
var viz_params = {bands:"B4,B3,B2", min:0, max:0.3};
var images_to_display = 5;

// Create list of dates for time series
var n_months = Date_End.difference(Date_Start,'month').round();
var dates = ee.List.sequence(0, n_months, num_months_in_interval);
var make_datelist = function(n) {
  return Date_Start.advance(n,'month');
};
dates = dates.map(make_datelist);

function addSentinel2NDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  //Thresholding
  //If NDVI less or equal to 0.3 => 0 else 1
  var thres = ndvi.gte(0.3).rename('thres');
  return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(thres);
}

var CreateMosaic = function(d1) {
  var start = ee.Date(d1);
  var end = ee.Date(d1).advance(num_months_in_interval, 'month');
  var date_range = ee.DateRange(start, end);
  var name = start.format('YYYY-MM').cat(' to ').cat(end.format('YYYY-MM'));
  return ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') 
    .filterDate(date_range)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
    .filterBounds(studyarea)
    .map(maskS2clouds)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(studyarea)})
    .map(addSentinel2NDVI)
    .qualityMosaic('thres')
    .set({name: name});
};
var list_of_images = dates.map(CreateMosaic);



// Add a few monthly mosaics to the map.
for (var i=0; i<images_to_display; i++) {
  var month_mosaic = ee.Image(list_of_images.get(i));
  var label = ee.String(month_mosaic.get('name')).getInfo();
  Map.addLayer(month_mosaic, viz_params, label);    
}

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(bandSubset, 'Mosaic', 
                {scale: 10, 
                 region: studyarea.getInfo()["coordinates"], 
                 type: 'float'});
```

How do I specify that I want to export just the `thres` band for the mosaics as a batch process?

I know the syntax for it to apply to an image collection, unable to figure it out in this instance.

```
//Export only the threshold band
//SYNTAX - imageCollection.select([old bands], [new band names])
var bandSubset = **VAR**.select(['thres'], ['thres']);
```